# How to resolve response.cookie is not a function: graphQL Nest.js

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

I'm trying to set up cookie to response (GraphQL, Nest.js), but getting an error - response.cookie is not a function. How can I resolve it?

app.module.ts file:

```
 GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [KitStatusModule],
      inject: [KitStatusService],
      useFactory: (kitStatusService: KitStatusService) => ({
        playground: true,
        autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gql',
        context: ({ req, res }) => {
          return { req, res }
        },
        introspection: true,
        cors: {
          credentials: true,
          origin: true,
        }
}
```

main.ts file:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';


async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.enableCors({
    origin: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

account.resolver.ts file:

```
async login(
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response,
    @GetExecutionContext() context: GqlExecutionContext,
    @Args('AccountInput') AccountInput: AccountInput
): Promise<AccountTokenOutput> {
    console.log(response.cookie('refreshtoken', 'refreshtoken'))
    return await this.accountService.login(AccountInput, context);
};
```

Comment: Are you using `express`?

Comment: no, app was created using const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

Comment: sorry, i was wrong. Express is using by default